# New to ASP and SQL server, How does the condition: IF(dtble.Rows.Count>0) work to match username and password?

Tags: asp.net

Can anyone explain me how does it matches username and password from data table and logs in the user?
DataTable dtForNameAndRole = LoadDataByQuery(sql);
try
{

```
            **if (dtForNameAndRole.Rows.Count > 0)**
                {
                    Session["username"] = dtForNameAndRole.Rows[0]["username"].ToString(); //userID;
                    Session["password"] = dtForNameAndRole.Rows[0]["password"].ToString(); //userID;
                  
        
                    txtpassword.Text = string.Empty;
                    txtusername.Text = string.Empty;
                    Response.Redirect("Dashboard.aspx");
```

Comment: Why you are retrieving all data from DB, you can only retrieve data that match with username and password. if you are doing that and the count of rows is greater than 0, then the user is valid.

Comment: Why not use the build in aspnet user management. Now you are building your own with what looks like plain text passwords.

Comment: As noted, the logon system is built in - you as a general rule should not be rolling your own. And you don't show the sql value in your above code. And we don't see/have the code for LoadDataByQuery - but I suppose it just returns a data table based on the SQL you pass - which we can't see how that string SQL was made or setup.  So how this matching occurs will be based on that SQL string - the one you not provied nor can we guess how that SQL string was made - but that without a doubt is where and how the datatable returns one row of data for that user (or 0 rows - if not valid user)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please use the below code it'll help you!

```
using (SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(connectionString)){

            //string user = txtEmail.Text;
            //string pass = txtPassword.Text;
            sqlcon.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select count(*) from [dbo].[Register] where Email=@Email and Password=@Password", sqlcon);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", ToSHA2569(txtPassword.Text));

            var isCorrectPassword = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            if ((int)isCorrectPassword >= 1)
            {
                //sqlcon.Close();  //taken care of because of the using command
                Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                //    sqlcon.Close();
                lblWrong.Text = "Password not correct";
            }
}
```